# How can I create a new layer from a one-to-many Relation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I am using QGIS 2.14 and am working with two layers: a layer of US Census Blocks and a layer of information on internet providers within each block. The internet provider layer is a CSV flat file, and the census block layer is a shapefile from the US Census TIGER site. I'd like to be able to create a unified layer of internet providers with information on each so I can, say, click "Verizon" and see everywhere Verizon offers service, or select just those blocks where the minimum speeds are in excess of X.

I understand I can't do a simple Join because it only joins one row of the CSV to each census block. I have set up a Relation in the Project Properties, which reflects the data structure I want, but I can't figure out how to make it just display in the map as a new layer.

I also tried creating a new layer by joining the CSV to the census block layer, but QGIS complained it wasn't a valid shapefile.

Comment: What does the data look like in the 'providers' table - perhaps some quick screen shots of the data structure would help...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this via the `Singleparts to Multipart` operation under `Vector` > `Geometry Tools` > `Singleparts to Multipart`.

The steps you'd need to take to do so is a simple `Join` that binds each internet provider to it's census block as a new field, and then use the `Singleparts to Multipart` algorithm to join all census blocks into a single feature. You can specify the new field representing the service provider field as the `Unique ID Field`, and the algorithm should link all polygons with that provider and output it as a new layer. When you select any of the polygons for that provider, it will highlight all other polygons with the same provider, as well.

That said, I am not entirely clear on the structure of your data -- specifically whether each census block has a single service provider, or if there are multiple service providers for each census block.

If there's a single service provider, you could get away with doing this series of steps just once and produce a single layer with all of the providers, otherwise you may need to repeat the process and create a new field for each provider (i.e., a column for Provider 1, column for Provider 2, etc.) with some sort of Boolean indication (yes/no) for each census block. You could then produce a series of layers, one for each provider, that gives a visual display of their coverage.

Hope this helps.